# emacs で、大きく設定が異なる設定ファイル(init.el) を編集ないし開発するには？

Tags: emacs

普段、 emacs の設定ファイル群を編集する際には、 emacs 自身でそれを行なっています。今、普段と大きく構成が異なる init.el に対して、これを実際に試しながら、必要とあれば修正をかけていきたいと思っています。その試行錯誤を行う際に利用するエディタには、 emacs を用いて、かつ普段使いの設定でもってこれを行いたいと考えています。

具体的にどういうことかというと、 [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) を使ってみたいのですが、いきなりこれでもって emacs 設定ディレクトリである .emacs.d を置き換えるのは学習曲線が急すぎると思っているので、

1. 普段の emacs で spacemacs の init.el を編集する。
2. 別プロセスで emacs を立ち上げ、 spacemacs の設定を読み込ませ、 spacemacs としての挙動を確認する

を実行したいな、と思っています。

これを行うにあたり、しかし、自分の知る限り .emacs.d の場所を切り替えながら emacs を起動する手法を自分は知らないので、これは果たしてこういうことは実現できるのだろうか、と思っている次第です。

## 質問

このような設定ファイル(.emacs.d/init.el)の編集ワークフローを実現したいときに、これができる手法・ツールなどはありますか？

Answer (score 1):

まず/path/to/init.elに以下のように記述します。

```
(when load-file-name
  (setq user-emacs-directory (file-name-directory load-file-name)))
```

起動時にこのelをロードしてやれば、~/.emacs.dの代わりに/path/toを設定ディレクトリとして使うことができます。

```
% emacs -q -l /path/to/init.el
```

とはいえ~/.emacs.dなどがハードコードされていないことが前提（代わりに`locate-user-emacs-file`などを使うべき）なので、spacemacs等が絶対に機能するとは言い切れないところがあります。

Answer (score 0):

部分的な回答ですが、`--no-init-file` オプションを使うと初期化ファイルを読み込まずに Emacs を起動できます。

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html